# PHP: How to use cron (or another method) to get a PHP script to run every second?

Tags: php, cron

If I have a cron job that runs every minute, and the first iterations runs for 62 seconds, will the second iteration wait to start until the first occurance ends, or can it happen that the same cron job runs concurrently?

To illustrate this, see scenario 1:

```
|0    |60   |120  |180  |240  |300
------ Cron Job 1 Taking 60 Seconds
      --------- Cron Job 2 Taking 90 Seconds
            ------ Cron Job 3 Taking 90 Seconds but overlapping with the previous cron job
```

Is the above what will happen, or will scenario 2 happen:

```
|0    |60   |120  |180  |240  |300
------ Cron Job 1 Taking 60 Seconds
      --------- Cron Job 2 Taking 90 Seconds
               XXX-------Cron Job 3 waiting til the next 1 minute interval starts
```

My concern is that there will be a period for 30 seconds marked XXX where there will be NO cron job running.

What am I trying to accomplish? I want to execute a PHP script every single second, indefinitely. It doesn't have to run once a second, but it must RUN, END, RUN, END, RUN, END. If an iteration takes 5 seconds, it must only start the next one after the first has ended. But it must never ever stop. The problem is that I can't determine the length of an iteration. One iteration could take 1 second, or it could take 5 seconds, or even longer.

1. Can cron do this? So that I can be guarenteed that the script will run every single second no matter what?
2. If not, how can I gaurentee that a PHP script runs indefinitely, one iteration after the other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using [supervisord](http://supervisord.org/) which solved all my problems.

Answer (score 2):

You can implement a simple locking mechanism as follow.

```
if(!locked()) {
    lock();
    // your code here
    unlock();
} else {
    echo "script already running";
}

function lock()   { file_put_contents("write.lock", 'running'); }
function locked() { return file_exists("write.lock"); }
function unlock() { return unlink("write.lock"); }
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes. cron starts the job but does not check if previously started completed. It's is not managing any job queue.

Answer (score 0):

It will start a second process regardless of another instance. In your script you could check for other processes (e.g. if a global PID file exists) already running or something, depends on what you need exactly.

Answer (score 0):

> will the second iteration start until the first occurence ends?

With Vixie cron which is default for most Unixes, the answer is "yes".

> how can I get true per second intervals on a linux system that executes a PHP script?

The question is strange, please reformulate. But if you want for a single instance of each script running simultaneously, use /usr/bin/flock or any other mutex tool.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using cron, you might look into "daemonizing" your script: [PEAR System Daemon](http://pear.php.net/package/System_Daemon)

From there, it seems like you would then need to build a simple job/task/worker queue, and use the daemon to dispatch and lock accordingly.