# Best tool to code a linux daemon that runs indefinitely?

Tags: linux

I want to know what are the alternatives to write a daemon that runs a PHP script indefinitely. In other words: execute PHP script ---> process ---> complete ---> repeat.

Can this be written in Bash? Or C? Is there perhaps a Linux tool I can install that can run something like this for me indefinitely? What approaches are commonly used to handle this task?

Update: im using centos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is such a common problem that people already wrote several utilities to do just that (in general they are called watchdogs).

You can compare the available options and inspect the sources of the one you like more. Some of them are:

- if you are in Ubuntu, try [upstart](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/).
- [daemontools](http://cr.yp.to/daemontools.html)
- [supervisord](http://supervisord.org/) (my favorite).

You can run the task periodically using cron, but it is hard to prevent concurrency (it is hard to do it well, dealing with locks, stale locks, etc.).

Comment: supervisord rocks my world. thank you!

Answer (score 0):

qiuickest would be what you know if it can meet your functional and perf requirements. Bash - usually easiest, perl - powerful, c - only if you really know what you are doing. You can use php itself if you know it best.

you can create a cron job to execute your php script. Or daemonify your program with an external program. It is easy to create a daemon with perl, will not be surprised if php also can fork as a daemon process.

bash solution:

```
cd /
while :; do php /path/myprog.php >> /var/log/myphplog.log; done </dev/null >/dev/null 2>/dev/null &
disown
```

You can put this code in rc.local or create a new init script. Log rotation would be good to have as well.

Comment: With cron I run into this problem --> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15933355/php-how-to-use-cron-or-another-method-to-get-a-php-script-to-run-every-second

Comment: @coderama, added example in answer